# TEMP TABLES remove WARNING: Could not compute bytes processed estimate for script

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there way to remove the above issue when I have a lot of temp tables and converting them to cte gives resources exceeded issue. Also does this error impact results in any way or is it fine to have this error?

I tried converting all my TEMP TABLES to cte but got resources exceeded error.